# Are 結局 and てしまう equivalent in terms of expressing "end up doing something"?

Tags: pragmatics

Out of the following two sentences, which one is more natural to say "I ended up eating all ice-cream"?

> 結局はアイスクリームを全部食べた。
>
> アイスクリームを全部食べてしまった。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use 結局, there has to be some time for hesitation, consideration, struggle, etc., before the action. It focuses on the circumstances before the action was done. It's similar to "after all" in English.

> - 太りそうなので5分考えたが、結局はアイスクリームを全部食べた。
> - 1か月勉強したが、結局試験に落ちた。

～てしまった can indicate something was simply undesirable, or something was regrettable as an afterthought.

> - 兄のものとは知らず、冷蔵庫のアイスクリームを食べてしまった。
> - 今朝、交通事故を目撃してしまった。

You can use 結局 and ～てしまった at the same time.

> - 太りそうなので5分考えたが、結局はアイスクリームを全部食べてしまった。